# Event Calendar WP не правильно отображается на странице

Tags: php, wordpress, calendar, shortcode

Всем доброго дня.
Проблема следующая. Криво отображается календарь на WP. Вставляю через шорткод. То есть изменения на нем видны, но отображается криво. Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Вопрос не имеет отношения ни к WP, ни к плагину. Стили кривые на сайте, вот поэтому так и отображается. Отключите все остальные плагины, смените тему на стандартную - и вы увидите, что всё в порядке.

Comment: Стили не пересекаются , значит подключены неправильно , я размещаю календарь через шорт код , как то можно повлиять при этом на стили ?

Comment: Какая разница, как вы размещаете - через шорткод или ещё как-то. Стили плагин запускает при инициализации, заааадого до того, как WP начинает выводить страницу.

Comment: В общем у меня получилось вывести корректный плагин только после того как я в хеде прописал линки css файла плагина. Не нашел как они прописаны в самом плагине поэтому прописал вручную у себя.

Comment: Тема - самопальная?

Comment: Да вроде нет, это event calendar WD

Comment: Я вас не про плагин спрашиваю, а про тему, установленную на сайте.

Comment: Со всем разобрался дело было как всегда во внимательности, тема была самописная , не подцепил head и footer .поэтому не отображались скрипты и стили.

Comment: Сколько раз уж говорил - не пишите свои темы.